# Special characters in JavaScript search

Tags: javascript

I have a search function that searches for a customer by the name and the city.
You type in part of the name, add a plus sign and then part of the city `([Customer]+[City])`.

This is what I currently use:

```js
filter = "substringof('" + searchText[0].toLowerCase() + "', Name) and substringof('" + searchText[1].toLowerCase() + "', Address1_City)";
```

This works fine until the customer has an ampersand (&) in the name, then it won't work.
I have examples of a customer name being something like "A&L" or "A+G". You end up having to type `L+[City]`, which means that I get every customer in that city with an L in their name.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you want to do it properly, have two separate fields and two separate URL parameters for name and city.

Comment: It's quite unclear what your code does. Where does `searchText` come from, and what is its exact value? (Post it as JSON if possible). What is the expected result? What does this `substringof` thing do, are you building SQL here? Where are you splitting the user input on the `+` sign? And what does this have to do with ampersands?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code generates a string, which it'll do just fine with special characters.

For example:

```
var searchText = ['A&L', 'Denver'];

var filter = "substringof('" + searchText[0].toLowerCase() + "', Name) and substringof('" + searchText[1].toLowerCase() + "', Address1_City)";
```

becomes `substringof('a&l', Name) and substringof('denver', Address1_City)`

Could it be that you then pass this string somewhere where the actual search takes place, and that's where the special char is not being handled correctly?